# Connection interrupted error when loading image from disk using SDWebImage in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, sdwebimage

I get this error when loading multi images from disk. I used `SDWebImage` to load image but still get this error then app crashed. I dont know what this error is. Pls give me adivse. Thanks much.

```
 Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x322eb614> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x322eb86c> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
```

Here is the code I used to create the list thumbnail for scrollview

```
 -(void) createPropertyThumbnails:(NSArray*) array
    {
        int xCoord=10;
        int yCoord=7;
        int buffer = 7;

        for (int pos = 0; pos < array.count; pos++) {
// CREATE VIEW CONTAINS UIIMAGEVIEW HERE
            ThumbnailView* thumbnaiCell = [[humbnailView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord,THUMBNAIL_WIDTH , THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT) andURLImage:array[pos]];
            thumbnaiCell.delegate = self;
            //set selected for 1st item
            if(pos ==0)
            {
                _selectedCell =thumbnaiCell;
                [_selectedCell setSelectedCell:YES];
            }

            xCoord = xCoord + THUMBNAIL_WIDTH  + buffer;

            [self.thumbnailScrollView addSubview:thumbnaiCell];
        }

        [self.thumbnailScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(xCoord, self.thumbnailScrollView.frame.size.height)];

    }


    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andURLImage:(NSString*) url
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {

            [self setupProjectThumbnail:frame andURLImage:url];

        }
        return self;
    }

    -(void) setupProjectThumbnail:(CGRect) frame andURLImage:(NSString*) url
    {
        //create load image from cache
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:url ofType:nil];
        NSURL *ImageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
        if (ImageURL) {
            SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
            [manager downloadImageWithURL:ImageURL
                                  options:0
                                 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                                     // progression tracking code
                                 }
                                completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                    if (image) {
                                        // do something with image

                                        // imageview
                                        UIImageView* imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
                                        imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
                                        [self addSubview:imageview];
                                    }
                                }];
        }

    }
```

Comment: plz post the code where u think its crashing.

Comment: Can't help with this particular problem. But I would suggest to try [DFImageManager](https://github.com/kean/DFImageManager), it's easy to integrate and it uses NSURLSession instead of NSURLConnection, which is getting deprecated starting with iOS 9. I haven't encountered any problems with file:// URLs before.